# How to apply a default-restriction on Entity-Bean @OneToMany Relationships

Tags: java, orm, jpa, ejb-3.0, one-to-many

I have two entity models, Customer and Order. Each customer could have **thousands** of orders. I have a OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship between these two entities.

How do I restrict this relationship's list to only top 10 orders?

Is it possible to apply 'WHERE' condition as an attribute on @OneToMany or not?

Like:

```
@OneToMany("Where Order.orderNo > 100")
```

My problem is when the object created by Entity Manager all Orders are created in memory.
**Lazy loading can not** solve my consideration, because I need to get top 10 orders in default construction.

Answer (score 5):

> I mean if it is possible to apply 'WHERE' condition as an attribute on @OneToMany or not?

Not with standard JPA. But some providers have extensions for this. For example, Hibernate does have a `@Where` annotation:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Where(clause="1=1")
public Set<Ticket> getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}
```

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide

  - [2.4.6. Collection related annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection)

Comment: What should we do for standard JPA?

Comment: @Navid: Apart from using a JPQL query, nothing, JPA does not provide support for this.

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not support this.  But in EclipseLink you can use an Expression to filter a relationship.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/MappingSelectionCriteria