# JPA: Conditionally fetch some of the child-objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am attempting to create a *NamedQuery* for the *Parent* object that retrieves all available *Parent*-objects  from the DB, and conditionally fetches some of the *Child*-objects in the same query. E.g. the query should retrieve all parent-objects and fetch the children which have *year=2012* for each parent object. The rest of the child objects should not be fetched. I attempted to play arround with a *LEFT JOIN FETCH*, but the result was that some of the parent-objects where also excluded. But then again, im new to the *FETCH*-statement.

Is there any way to achieve the task described above? Any help is much appreciated. The relevant code of my *Parent*-object is listed below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx", name = "Parent")
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 */
.....................
/**
 */

@Column(name = "status")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
String status;
/**
 */
/**
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@XmlElement(name = "", namespace = "")
java.util.Set<xxx.xxx.xxx.Child> children;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what you want using the @Where annotation - you should be able to just add an annotation as below to your children property

```
@Where(clause="year=2012")
```

Also, see this question: [How to apply a default-restriction on Entity-Bean @OneToMany Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514672/how-to-apply-a-default-restriction-on-entity-bean-onetomany-relationships)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this argument would be static right? In the sense that it will always be applied? I would like to be able to perform the query with year 2012,2011,2010 etc. So is it possible to do the same but only with an input parameter which i can alter? :)